# MySQL ORDER BY two clauses

Tags: mysql

I am learning about the MySQL statement, `ORDER BY`. I ran into this tutorial where they show an example with two clauses. How is that possible? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY 
score DESC, date ASC;
```

How is that possible to have to order by two clauses? It doesn't make sense to me. How can your results be ordered twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will do something like:

```
   ORDER score descending
   IF there are two rows with same score
   ORDER date ascending
```

Simply, if you have this table

```
score    date
1        11111
1        11113
2        11112
```

this will get you result

```
score    date 
2        11112
1        11111
1        11113
```

Comment: Why would the score ID change for date 11113? Also, 11113 is not a date.

Comment: Sure, but it is not accurate because the data from column score and column date do not match any more

Answer (score 2):

First it orders by score, and then for any rows with the same score, it orders them by date.

E.g., this is sorted by `Score ASC, Date ASC`:

```
Score Date

1   2012/3/2
12  2012/3/1
46  2012/3/1
213 2012/3/1
213 2012/3/2
234 2012/3/1
234 2012/3/2
435 2012/3/1
435 2012/3/2
435 2012/3/2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT...
FROM..
ORDER BY 
score DESC, date ASC;
```

means that it will order first by `SCORE` (*descending*) then by `date` (*ascending*)

if you have records like this:

```
A      B
==========
10     100
10     200
20     300
40     500
```

by `ORDER BY A DESC, B ASC`

```
A     B
==========
40    500
20    300
10    100 
10    200
```

as you can see, there are 2 records of `10` and `B` will be order by `ascending` that's why you get `100 then 200` instead of `200 then 100`.